# Does ubuntu laptop needs to be shutdown ? or it can be running all the time?

Tags: 20.04

I have HP 250 G7 (i7) / 2019
I have ubuntu 20.04 LTS
My question is: do I need to shut down this computer? Or it can be running all the time?

I can see that everyday i only close laptop cover but it's still running so next day i just open laptop cover and its ready (just need to write user password). It is safe this usage? Im asking because on windows laptops i remember there was issue that long/many sleeps resolves blue screen or system failure.

Comment: It should be shutdown once in awhile, but does not need to everyday.  Some updates do like a restart also.  You are updating.  All OSs should be shutdown/restarted to clean out the software crud that adds up over time.  Would try to limit up time to about a week or two, hopefully same time as update needs a restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I need to shut down this computer?

No. You could use hibernate.

> Or it can be running all the time?

In theory yes. Linux/Ubuntu is made to run on systems that are on for long periods. The base of Ubuntu is also used for servers and those run several years between reboots.

In regards to notebooks: do consider using hibernation when inactive. It should improve the systems lifespan.